# Passing Multidimensional JSON Array to jQuery Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP array that I want to pass to the jQuery function that called it. However when I tried to retrieve the value of 'lat' the way i did below, I get the error `Cannot read property 'lat' of null`, obviously because I dont know how to access a multidimensional JSON array. Can anyone show me how?

**PHP Array**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [price] => 1600
        [bedroom] => 1
        [lat] => -71.119385
        [lng] => 42.373917
        [distance] => 6.65195429565453
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 1800
        [bedroom] => 1
        [lat] => -71.104248
        [lng] => 42.368172
        [distance] => 4.957829810472103
    )
}
```

This gets encoded into

**JSON**

```
[{"price":"1600","bedroom":"1","lat":"-71.119385","lng":"42.373917","distance":"6.65195429565453"},{"price":"1800","bedroom":"1","lat":"-71.104248","lng":"42.368172","distance":"4.957829810472103"}]
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#search_button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var search_location = $("#search_location").val();
        $.getJSON('index.php/main/get_places', {search_location: search_location}, function(json){
            $("#result").html(json.lat);
            console.log(json.lat);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json` is an array, so it won't have the property `lat`.

Try:

```
json[0].lat
```

To get the first object's lat property, for example.

Comment: `console.log(json[0].lat);` did not cause anything to be logged in the javascript console...

Comment: Then the `JSON` is not what you say it is :)

Comment: I checked the JSON string returned without using AJAX. That's really the JSON lol... Does this have to do with the `JSON` string not having any index numbers like `1:, 2:`

Comment: oh no.. I get the error `Cannot read property '0' of null` when using `json[0].lat`. Is there a way to check what is the json string received by the jquery function?

Comment: Ah, ok the response is probably not what you expect then. There are a few tools to look at what is going on, but I prefer to use the developer tools in Chrome (press ctl-shift-J to open - see the Network tab).

Comment: Thanks, found out that I should use a `echo` instead of `return` in my php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('index.php/main/get_places', {search_location: search_location}, function(json){
  $.each(json, function(key, val) {
      console.log(val.lat);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is returning as an array of objects, so you need to reference the scalar first. Change your references to json.lat into json[0].lat.

Then, if you need to you can write a for loop and reference it as json[i].lat, assuming that i is your iterator variable.

Answer (score 0):

json is an array of objects, just as it is in your php code.

So there are two lat values:

```
json[0].lat  // and
json[1].lat
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json` variable itself is null, as stated by the error message.  All the answers about accessing subindexes of `json` or iterating over it like an array will fail because of this.

Look at the documentation for jQuery's `getJSON` and `parseJSON`.  `getJSON` passes the server's response through `parseJSON` to convert it to a Javascript object.  `parseJSON` returns null "if you pass in nothing, an empty string, null, or undefined."

I would use your browser's debugger to look at the raw http response from the server, because that is likely the culprit.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/